# How to specific a dictionary for a TOML file in Julia?

Tags: julia

if I want to have a dictionary for entries in a TOML file, how can I set that up in Julia?

I want it to be something like:

```
["hello"]
world = Dict("z" => 25, "c" => 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can also use `TOML` module built into `Pkg` module without installing anything:

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.TOML.print(Dict("hello" => Dict("world" => Dict("hellow" => "wurld"))))

[hello.world]
hellow = "wurld"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can quite simply use TOML by doing the following:

`add https://github.com/JuliaLang/TOML.jl.git` in the package manager.

```
import TOML

TOML.print(Dict("hello" => Dict("world" => Dict("hellow" => "wurld"))))
```

which will output:

```
[hello.world]
hellow = "wurld"
```

[See the TOML.jl for more info.](https://github.com/JuliaLang/TOML.jl)